# Matlab version rpmordermap and rpmfreqmap

Tags: matlab

Are those functions only available in Matlab 2015b version or they are included in 2015a version also? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very bottom of MATLAB manual pages there is always an info about the time when given function was first introduced. For both of `rpm*map` functions:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

No, they are available from R2015b, as answered by @jojek.

Meanwhile, especially for older versions, you can find useful alternatives for Order-RPM function, for instance at [MatlabCentral](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange) with [Campbell diagrams](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2251-campbell), or [Vold-Kalman order tracking code](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32639-vold-kalman-order-tracking-code).